# Why for loop want take parameters of function in c#?

Tags: c#, parameters, for-loop, arguments

Why this code doesn't work?

```
    private void Function(int starts , int ends)
{
    int i = starts;
    int z = ends;

    for(i; i < z; i++)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

It's say: Error 3   Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement.

What to do to make code work?

Answer (score 7):

```
    What to do to make code work?
```

How about

```
for (; i < z; i++)
{
    [...]
}
```

OR why creating an extra variable `'z'` when you can do

```
for (int i = starts; i < ends; i++)
{
    [...]
}
```

Why your code doesn't not work!!

Because syntax of for loop is

```
for (initializer; condition; increment or decrement)
{

}
```

You were not initializing `i` in initializer. You could initialize it (as my second snippet) or remove initializer if you are initializing it in some earlier statement(as my first snippet).

Comment: or for (int i = starts; i < ends; i++)

Comment: What is the difference between his code and your second code? both will start from i

Comment: @aliboy38: Both will start from i but i am initializing it in for loop

Answer (score 2):

`i` in and of itself is not a statement, it's an expression. In the same way that you can-not simply write `i;` somewhere in your code. The initialization-part of a for-loop needs to be initialization; however, if (as is the case here) the loop is already initialized (`i` is already set), you can just omit it as Nikhil showed. Simply do `for(;i<z;i++)`.

Answer (score 1):

The first part of the for loop takes initialization statements. `i` is not a statement. If you don't want to initialize anything, you can leave that part empty, as in Nikhil's answer:

```
for(; i < z; i++) 
{ 
    [...] 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use outside-defined variables as indexers in for loops.

```
private void Function(int starts , int ends)
{
    // int i = starts; // don't do it. you're exposing yourself to headaches if/when you lose control of the value of i
    int z = ends;

    for(int i = starts; i < z; i++) //first statement of for loops initializes the indexer
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better answer is it not?

```
private void Function(int starts , int ends)
{
    for(int i = starts; i < ends; i++)
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```